# Aqueduct ORM multiple nested joins

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I am using Aqueudct ORM with data models like so:

```
    A
    |    (one-one)
    B
  / | \  (all many-one)
 C  C  C
```

and my Tables look like so:

```
class _A {
  B b;
}

class _B {
  @Relate(#c1Ref)
  C c1;
  @Relate(#c2Ref)
  C c2;
  @Relate(#c3Ref)
  C c3;
}

class _C {
  ManagedSet<B> c1Ref;
  ManagedSet<B> c2Ref;
  ManagedSet<B> c3Ref;
}
```

I want to write a query to fetch big fat `A`, but I can't figure it out.

So far, I have:

```
final query = Query<A>(context)
  ..join(object: (a) => a.b)
   //Note the non-cascading dot
  .join(object: (b) => b.c1);
```

This gives me `A` with `B` but with only `c1`. How do I write a query such that I get `c2` and `c3` as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The join method returns a new query object. This query is a child of the original query, and controls the parameters of the query on the joined table. That is, you can apply a where condition to the new query object that applies to the joined table. In your case, you want to assign the new query object to a variable first and then set up each join. I’m on mobile right now so this may not come out great:

```
  final query = Query<A>(context);
  final bQuery = query.join(object: (a) => a.b)
       ..join(object: (b) => b.c1)
       ..join(object: ( b) => b.c2)
        ..join(object: (b) => b.c3);
```

Note that you didn’t really have put this on into a variable here, but I did to illustrate the point. You would execute ‘query’ here, not ‘bQuery’.

Y

Comment: Yes this works, thanks! My issue was that I also have a `.where` on the `Query<A>`, and I couldn't add the joins before or after it. I did not know that `.join` modifies the query itself; I thought it was always returning a new query object. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! And yes, the parent query keeps a reference to the newly created query object.